# CodeGenSuppress and CodeGenModel not being applied to AutoRest generated code

Tags: autorest

I am attempting to customize two aspects of code generation for a c# client:

- The name of a model (`Person` to `PersonCustomized` via the `[CodeGenModel]` attribute
- Suppressing the generation of a method (`AddPersonAsync`) via the `[CodeGenSuppress]` attribute.

Open API file / command / options are included in the repro here: https://github.com/rquackenbush/AutoRestCustomizationRepro

**Expected behavior**

- The `Person` model should be generated as `PersonCustomized`
- The `AddPersonAsync` method should not be generated.

**Actual Behavior**

- The `Person` model is being generated as `Person`
- The `AddPersonAsync` method is still being generated.

**Question**

How do I get the customizations to apply?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh - you have to specify the folder differently using `$(this-folder)`:

```yaml
input-file: swagger.json
csharp: true 
output-folder: $(this-folder)/Generated
namespace: AutoRestCustomizationRepro
skip-csproj: true
clear-output-folder: true
override-client-name: AutoRestCustomizationRepro
generation1-convenience-client: true
project-folder: $(this-folder)
```